# Show that $ Tf:TM \rightarrow TN \text{ is } \mathcal C^{\infty}$?

Tags: solution-verification, differential-topology

Let $ \mathrm{M} $ and $ \mathrm {N} $ be two differentiable manifolds, and $ f : M \rightarrow N$ an application $\mathcal C^{\infty} $. Show that $$ Tf:TM \rightarrow TN  \text{ is } \mathcal C^{\infty}$$
**My attempt :**
Let $ \pi_{M}: TM \longrightarrow M$ and $ \pi_{N}: TN \longrightarrow N $ be the tangent bundles on $ \mathrm {M} $ and $ \mathrm {N} $ respectively
$ TF:TM \longrightarrow TN $ the tangent map of $f $.
Let two overlap of M and N be given by:
$$
M = \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} U_{\alpha} \text{ and } N = \bigcup_{\alpha \in J} V_{\alpha}
$$
Then $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
TM @>{Tf}>> TN\\
@V{\pi_1}VV @V{\pi_2}VV \\
M @>{f}>> N
\end{CD}$$
Since $\pi_1:TM\to M$ and $\pi_2:TN\to N$ are two bundles then $$ \varphi_{\alpha} \; : \; U_{\alpha} \times F \; \; \rightarrow \pi_M ^ {- 1} (U _ {\alpha}) $$
$$ \Psi _{\alpha}: V_{\alpha} \times F \rightarrow \pi_N ^ {- 1} (V_{\alpha}) $$
Which gives us the following commutative diagram:
\begin{CD}
U_{\alpha} \times F @>{\varphi_{\alpha}}>> \pi^{-1}(U_{\alpha})\\
@V{T}VV @V{Tf}VV \\
V_{\alpha}\times F' @>{\psi_{\alpha}}>> \pi^{-1}(V_{\alpha})
\end{CD}

so we have $ Tf =\Psi _{\alpha} \circ T \circ \varphi _{\alpha}^ {- 1} $ with $ T(x, y) = (f (x), P (y)) $ where $ P $ is defined as the projection map. therefore T is $ C ^ {\infty} $, So $ Tf $ is $ C ^ {\infty} $.
Is my solution true?

Comment: No, you want $T(x,y) = (\overline f(x), D\overline f(x) y)$ where $\overline f$ is the expression of $f$ in the charts you have chosen and $D\overline f$ is the map $U_a\to Lin(F, F')$ given by the differential of $\overline f$ in these coordinates.

Comment: additionally you need to make the coordinates a bit smaller, so that the image of $U_a$ actually lies in $V_a$. I also notice your $U_a$ aren't actually coordinate charts, but just trivialisations of the tangent bundles. This will make it harder to define $D\overline f(x)$ and harder to argue why its smooth. Better to do it in coordinate charts.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Can you justify why you have $P$ in the definition of $T$?